# Technique for finding arbitrary matrix powers.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

How would one go about finding an expression of $A^k$ where $k$ is an arbritrary positive integer and
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}1& 4\\ 2 & 3\end{pmatrix}?
$$

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** If you could write
$$
A = P\begin{pmatrix}\lambda_1 & 0 \\ 0 & \lambda_2\end{pmatrix}P^{-1}\tag{1}
$$
then we would have the formula
$$
A^k = P\begin{pmatrix}\lambda_1^k & 0 \\ 0 & \lambda_2^k\end{pmatrix}P^{-1}
$$
Can you find $P$, $\lambda_1$, and $\lambda_2$ so that (2) holds? If not, try reading up on [diagonalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_diagonalization#Diagonalization).

Comment: How do I write with those math symbols. I know it's not related but it seems really useful.

Comment: @user149635 If you hit "edit" below my answer, then you can see my code. Better yet, you can check out the tutorial here: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: How come, in the formula above when you raised A to the K that you didn't raise P and P inverse to the K? Is it because they divide out to one? Or did I misunderstand that step?

Comment: @user149635 Write out a few examples for small $k$. It's important to note that $P^{-1}P=I$.

Comment: @Alan But using Mathematica doesn't give us a general formula. What  about $A^g$ where $g$ is Graham's number? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham's_number